# NLP: Tagging an url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, nlp

What would be the best way to extract 3 tags with its relevance, from an URL?

For example: given http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/tdd-is-dead-long-live-testing.html

The result could be:

```
Test-driven-development: 0.7
Rails: 0.2
Programming: 0.1
```

Ps.:

1) it's for a Rails application. So, good answers should include an API request, or maybe a Ruby Gem that does this.

2) The relevances doesn't really have to be normalized (sum up to 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do topic modelling on the contents of the URL: http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/programs_data/toolbox.htm